# Packaged Electron app runs against different instances of Chromium

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I am developing an application which has published tens of versions, during which we have updated electron and electron-builder several times.

Recent I have [used](https://github.com/LiskHQ/lisk-desktop/pull/2827) `electron-builder-notarize` to notarize the application. Ever since I have noticed that, the app runs against a different instance of Chromium. I can confirm that since my devtools settings are different when I run the [old version](https://github.com/LiskHQ/lisk-desktop/releases/tag/v1.24.0) of my application compared to when I run the new version.

Additionally, I see different sets of bookmarks and settings (which use localStorage) running the old or the new versions of the application.

localStorage is restricted to the application origin, I confirm that in both versions the app runs over `localhost:3000`.

How can I configure the release process to use the same instance of Chromium? Or better said, how can I build the application and not loose access to previously stored data on localStorage.

Comment: The Chromium version used is tied to the Electron version used, so I'd suspect that some software along the way packages a wrong version of Electron.

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner I can confirm that I use electron@4.2.4 in both versions of app. but we have updated the Electron in the past and it hasn't affected our localStorage access.

Comment: How specifically have you confirmed that the same version is being used?

Comment: @pushkin Checked package-lock for other installations. And didn't notice it being downloaded/installed during the packaging process.

Comment: @pushkin not sure if this was enough, but that's all I could do.

Comment: could you try logging `process.versions.electron` and `process.versions.chrome` inside your renderer process and check devtools to verify?

Comment: @pushkin Electron version is 4.2.4, I just noticed another problem. Since we run over localhost:3000, if another application is using this port, Electron switches to an random port which is also a reason to no access the previously stored values. but this is only when port 3000 isnt free.